# Unity netcode for gameobject can't connection host

Tags: unity-game-engine, multiplayer

When I am trying to establish host，unity will text me some errors.

[some errors are "'Server is shutting down due to network transport start failure of UnityTransport!' and 'Server failed to bind'"]

My netcode for the gameobject package version is 1.0.2, and I import the sample scene "Bootstrap", the same situation occurred(when I click button  Host down).

Answer (score 1):

For me it was to change the IP address in the NetworkManager to the IP of my development computer in our Home-Network.

Answer (score 1):

My problem was that my Mac was using port 7777 for something else.

Changing the port number fixed my problem.

Unity Transport → Connection data → Port `7778`

[image: Port settings in unity transport]

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED！
you can read the part of [docs](https://docs-multiplayer.unity3d.com/netcode/current/api/Unity.Netcode.NetworkManager/#remarks) NetworkManager
...=-=...

EDITED: March 6th,2023

if you have any issues about this subject，you can read the docs first,and how solved my problem?Reconfiguring the Unity Transport conponent,the normal `port` is 7777,i changed to 6666,this method can solovd my problem :).i'm a beginner,if my answer has any problems,welcom to comment it!

Thanks for others' answers.And also can try to change the `port` more.

Comment: Solving your own problem is always good, perhaps you can elaborate how you actually solved it, so the next person can learn something from you.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion！if you have any issues about this subject，you can read the [docs](https://docs-multiplayer.unity3d.com/netcode/current/api/Unity.Netcode.NetworkManager/#remarks) first,and how solved my problem?Reconfiguring the Unity Transport conponent,the normal port is 7777,i changed to 6666,this method can solovd my problem :).i'm a beginner,if my answer has any problems,welcom to comment it!

Comment: Explain how you solved it, please do not post a link only

Answer (score 0):

Similarly, I was able to connect to 127.0.0.1 but not my actual IP address.

Ticking "Allow Remote Connections?" in the UnityTransport Script settings in my NetworkManager fixed this for me.

Tick this box:
[image: Tick this box]